# Remove Blank ROWS from CSV files in php

Tags: php, csv, row, blank-line

Is it possible to remove all blank ROWS from a CSV file?

I'm trying to count all rows from a CSV file but would like to exclude lines that doesn't contain a value on a specific column or the whole row.

This is what I'm using to count the rows as of the moment.

```
$import = file($target_path, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$num_rows = count($import);
echo $num_rows;
```

sample:

```
Jun,Bronse,137 Raven,Princeton,TX,75407,2147088671,Nell@Gmail.Com,1990,CHEVROLET,K1500,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
Nella,Brown,111 Venna St,Princeton,TX,75407,2147177671,lakb@Gmail.Com,1993,CHEVROLET,K1500,,
Jun,Bronse,137 Raven,Princeton,TX,75407,2147088671,Nell@Gmail.Com,1990,CHEVROLET,K1500,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
Jun,Bronse,137 Raven,Princeton,TX,75407,2147088671,Nell@Gmail.Com,1990,CHEVROLET,K1500,,
```

Comment: `empty()` along with `foreach()` and `explode()` are a good place to start

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$lines = file("test.csv", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$num_rows = count($lines);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $csv = str_getcsv($line);
    if (empty($csv[SPECIFIC_COLUMN])) {
        $num_rows--;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to check a specific column, but just filter out rows where all columns are empty, change it to:

```
    if (count(array_filter($csv)) == 0) {
```

Comment: +1 for `str_getcsv()`, never even heard of it before. I'm assuming the advantage of that function compared to `explode()` is that it would handle strings with commas in them correctly? (e.g. `1,2,"Here's a string, check it out",3,4`)

Comment: how about just getting a blank row not a specific column?

Comment: @telexper `!array_filter($csv)` would return true if all values of the array are empty, but could become time consuming (better to just use a simple `foreach`)... That part is easy

Comment: If all the columns are blank, the specific column will be blank, so that check will do it.

Comment: @Barmar but not exclusively for an entirely blank row

Comment: Can't use function return value in write context in /.../... on line "if (empty(array_filter($csv)))"

Comment: @ Barmar I have a similiar question: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703373/)

Answer (score 3):

For empty rows:

```
$lines = file("test.csv", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$num_rows = count($lines);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $csv = str_getcsv($line);
    if (!array_filter($csv)) {
        $num_rows--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been useful to me as of august 2018.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = "test.csv";

if (($fp = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
    $rows = explode("\n", $fp);
    $csv = "";

    foreach($rows as $r) {
        if(str_replace(array(" ", ","), "", $r) != "")
            $csv .= $r."\n";
    }

    file_put_contents($filename, $csv);;
}
```

Comment: Empty row could be stored in the CSV as `,,,,,,,,` (for example.) Your code would produce inaccurate results. Not to mention @telexper has already used `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`

Answer (score 0):

Basically what Barmar already posted, but if you need to process (many) large* files, I'd recommend to give `rtrim` (or `ltrim`) a try, since usually those are a bit faster for a task like yours:

```
$lines = file("test.csv", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$num_rows = count($lines);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!rtrim($line, ',')) {
        $num_rows--;
    }
}
```

---

*<sub>By large I mean that large that it's really worth it. Don't waste your time doing micro-optimizations.</sub>

Answer (score -5):

use notepad++ to open .csv file. Then search for `^\*s` goto find and replace and click replace all button. This should solve your problem.